# What is the Django equivalent for the Flask example used by Google API Python Client?

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to follow the examples for getting OAuth up and running with a Python app as described by Google's API.

They use a flask example only.

In the case of this, for example:

```
@app.route('/test')
def test_api_request():
  if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
    return flask.redirect('authorize')

  # Load credentials from the session.
  credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
      **flask.session['credentials'])
  ...
```

How would I know what to replace the `**flask.session['credentials']` with in my Django application?
I am still attempting to do the same thing, but without Flask.

What is the Django equivalent for `flask.session`?

The code is taken from here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app#example

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there are few resources available in the reference itself you can find some help using these links
[Using Django](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/django)

Also, a working sample application is provided by the API guide 
[Sample App](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples/django_sample)

For further information, you should read the [OAuth guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth).